# Searchable stack

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm looking for a stack-like data structure that allows efficient searching of the contents. Effectively I want a structure that both maintains the order in which elements are inserted, but is also searchable faster than O(n) by value of the elements (in order to prevent duplicates).

The elements are small (pointers), and my primary concern is memory efficiency, so simply using two complementary data structures (one to maintain the order and one to search) is definitely not ideal.

Comment: Do you expect to be able to push and pop elements in O(1) as you would in a typical non-searchable stack?

Comment: How many items do you expect there to be in the structure? If it's small, a linear search is fast.

Comment: @aix: yes, this would be very nice, as pushing and popping will occur very frequently.

Comment: @GMan: typically no more than 100 items, but again these need to be searched very frequently (once on every insert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't underestimate the memory-efficiency of two data structures. You should try the straightforward boost multi-index container library first, and see if its memory footprint is sufficient.

The first less usual data structure I have thought of as an answer was a skip list; however, this list won't do because you are searching for a different key than the one you are ordering on. Just noting for others who have the same idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of boost::multi_index, I hadn't realized it also supports sequenced indices. I'll use that until (and unless) it ends up taking too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary concern really is a memory efficiency then you better to use a primitive linked list data structure. Linear search complexity is not so bad unless you have proven the inverse.

Or you may try to use any data structure which provides an efficient search with two small upgrades: each element should contain a link to the previously added element, so making a reversed list, and you should store a link to the head of this list, i.e. last added element. These upgrades are required to ease pushing and popping elements.

Comment: I also like the idea of setting up a sequenced linked list within an ordered container, but since boost::multi_index saves me some work I'll accept thiton's answer and upvote yours.